# Why some text disappear (can not see) when test on mobile device?

Tags: css, viewport, responsive

Why some text disappear (can not see) when test on mobile device ?

I want to show all text when test on mobile device. by full size text how can i do ?

```
<html>
<head>  
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>
<body style=" margin: 0; ">
<div style="
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #a5d670;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 48px;
">After clicking the submit button, FormValidation will submit the form if all the fields are valid.
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to remove absolute position and set auto height

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `height` property to `48px`. On a narrow screen, the text has to wrap so it can be shown. However, with that small height, it won't appear.

I suggest you to use `min-height` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `overflow: hidden;` and the width of the viewport is too thin the part of the text that does not fit the width will disappear.

Removing that will make the text break into more lines, but as you defined `height: 48px;` the text will be rendered out of the green background, in order for the remaining text to appear you should do:

```
<div style="
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #a5d670;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 48px;
">After clicking the submit button, FormValidation will submit the form if all the fields are valid.
</div>
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/rLqrk0wd/1/) for the result